# non recursive binary tree insert() method not working

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have written a binary tree code for inserting elements into it in non-recursive method. The code is not working as intended. Regardless of how many times I debug the code, nothing seems to be wrong but I am getting wrong results. I am hoping you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

```
void insert(int element){
    if(root == NULL){
        struct elemq *node;
        node = (struct elemq *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemq));
        node->ele = element;
        node->left = NULL;
        node->right = NULL;
        root = node;
        cout << root->ele << "\n";
    }
    else{
        struct elemq *ref;
        ref = root;
        while(ref != NULL){
            if(element <= ref->ele){
                if(ref->left == NULL){
                    struct elemq *node;
                    node = (struct elemq *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemq ));
                    node->ele = element;
                    node->left = NULL;
                    node->right = NULL;
                    ref->left = node;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    ref = ref->left;
                }
            }
            else if(element > ref->ele){
                if(ref->right == NULL){
                    struct elemq *node;
                    node = (struct elemq *)malloc(sizeof(struct elemq ));
                    node->ele = element;
                    node->left = NULL;
                    node->right = NULL;
                    ref->right = node;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    ref = ref->right;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I try to insert an element, each element is being treated as `root`, not only the first time. So, every time, the condition `if(root == NULL)` is `true`. I declared `root` as global variable and initialized it to `NULL` in `main()`. I came to know this by putting `cout <<` in the first `if()` condition. I modified my previous post to this new question.

Comment: Some code somewhere is trashing root.  Insert `cout << root << "\n";` all over the place and seen if it transitions back to zero.  Then find where it happens...

Comment: its my mistake. sorry. each time i am inserting an element, i am making root as null in the main. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
node = ref->left;
```

You want

```
ref->left = node;
```

and similar for the ref->right

Comment: I made the change. Still, every time i try to insert an element, each element is being treated as root, not only at first time. So, every time, the condition if(root == NULL) is being true. I declared root as global variable and initialized it to NULL in main().

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mistakenly setting the node that you are adding to the references, instead of setting the left and right references to the node you are adding.
Change `node = ref->left` to `ref->left = node`, and likewise for the right.